# Django Migration Is Failing

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django/postgresql application. Whenever I run my latest migration, I receive the following error:

> ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for package(speciality, title)

I believe I need to customize the migration, but what change I should make.

This is the migration:

> operations = [
>
> ```
>     migrations.AddField(
>
>         model_name='package',
>
>         name='speciality',
>
>         field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='specialities', to='speciality.Speciality', blank=True),
>
>     ),
>
>     migrations.AlterField(
>
>         model_name='package',
>
>         name='title',
>
>         field=models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50),
>
>     ),
>
>     migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
>
>         name='package',
>
>         unique_together=set([]),
>
>     ),
>
>     migrations.RemoveField(
>
>         model_name='package',
>
>         name='speciality',
>
>     ),
>
> ]
> ```

This is my current table configuaration for this model:

> sleepyfish=# \d package
>                                        Table "public.package"
>       Column     |           Type           |                      Modifiers
>   ---------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------  id            | integer                  | not null default
>   nextval('package_id_seq'::regclass)  created_at    | timestamp with
>   time zone | not null  updated_at    | timestamp with time zone | not
>   null  title         | character varying(50)    | not null  description
>   | text                     |   status        | boolean
>   | not null  price         | numeric(8,2)             | not null 
>   speciality_id | integer                  |  Indexes:
>       "package_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
>       "package_speciality_id_3aeb5c97679442e4_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (speciality_id, title)
>       "package_66db61fe" btree (speciality_id) Foreign-key constraints:
>       "package_speciality_id_4255b58fe1ae00c0_fk_speciality_id" FOREIGN KEY (speciality_id) REFERENCES speciality(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY
>   DEFERRED Referenced by:
>       TABLE "claimedpackage" CONSTRAINT "claimedpackage_package_id_9e1da358fbb9a46_fk_package_id" FOREIGN KEY
>   (package_id) REFERENCES package(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
>       TABLE "package_service" CONSTRAINT "package_service_package_id_3b0ea08bfcd8da76_fk_package_id" FOREIGN
>   KEY (package_id) REFERENCES package(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

Comment: Are you defined some value by default to Speciality value?

Comment: Could you show the code of your `models.py`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are running into [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23906) documented Django bug. The bug was [triaged as invalid](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23906#comment:2) (and rightly so), so unfortunately there is no clean solution to the problem.

The unique together constraint in the database definition is shown as

```
"package_speciality_id_3aeb5c97679442e4_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT,
btree (speciality_id, title)
```

If you want to remove this constraint, you will need to ensure the `unique_together` definition in the migration file is consistent with the database definition. Try replacing the `AlterUniqueTogether` line with this:

```
migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
    name='package',
    unique_together=set([('speciality_id', 'title')]),
),
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an alternative if answer from `arjun27` no solving your problem.

Today I got same problem (exact keyword with the question) when I tried to remove unique_together from Django Model. I'm using Django 1.11.

Read documentation and reference from `arjun27`, as I understand, the migration process will try to find UNIQUE CONTRAINST on Postgresql for field `(speciality, title)`, using above case.

I try to find the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on table but not found.

so, I create the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT directly from SQL console.

```
ALTER TABLE package ADD UNIQUE (speciality, title)
```

then I re-run the migration.

hope it helps.

Comment: you can also add SQL code in your migration file. see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunSQL

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone runs into the same issue as I did:
I have a multi-tenant system wherein each tenant has its own schema, with the `public` schema left empty.

When Django tries to inspect the current state of the database to delete the real unique constraint matching the historical one, it only looks inside the `public` schema, ignoring the schema information set in `OPTIONS` from the `DATABASES` setting.

There are a couple of tickets open regarding this issue, with no real resolution in sight: [#6148](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148) and [#22673](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22673).

You can always write your own database backend to circumvent the issue, or submit a pull-request to Django!